# Find Computers and the Execution policy

Tags: powershell

I run this command to find execution policy of each computer. I'm looking for output of computer name and their respective execution policy.

```
**$Results = 
Get-ExecutionPolicy | Select-Object @{l='ComputerName';e={$env:computername}}
$Results | out-file -FilePath c:\temp\Process3.csv**
```

I only see computer name and not the execution policy. What am I missing ?

ps: Invoke-command doesn't in my environment due to some issues WinRM. So that's not an option for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're disregarding the output when you use a calculated property to implement only the *ComputerName* column. You need to also select the value that was output by `Get-ExecutionPolicy`:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy |
    Select-Object @{
        Name = 'ComputerName';
        Expression = { $env:computername }
    }, @{
        Name = "Policy";
        Expression = { $_ } 
    }
```

Comment: I added $Result to make it for export to csv. so this is my final look $Result = Get-ExecutionPolicy |
    Select-Object @{
        Name = 'ComputerName';
        Expression = { $env:computername }
    }, @{
        Name = "Policy";
        Expression = { $_ } 
    }

    $Result | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path C:\Temp\policyext.csv

Comment: You can pipe directly to `Export-Csv` if you don't care about the output to your console: `...} | Export-Csv ...`.